# Internet wifi video streaming at low speed

Tags: android, video, adb, buffering, bitrate

I have one command to change specification for wifi adapter

Can me someone help to finish the project?  at 15 mbts  speed it must work app with video streaming ( youtube netflix or Iptv)

Without buffering!!!

What must I change in command line

adb shell dumpsys wifi | sed -u 9p

4-8 sec win by buffering

How I can 20 sec win by buffering ( without Internet)

R

Comment: Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). I have no idea what is your question